# Why does pip not work from make commands but work outside of it?

Tags: python, makefile, pip, zsh-alias

pip commands are not working when i run a make command. Changing it to pip3 works and adding an alias (alias pip="pip3") in my zshrc makes pip work from the command line but still not from the Makefile.

Comment: `Makefile`s know nothing about shell aliases. Use `pip3` or even better use `python -m pip`

Comment: As phd said, use `python -m pip`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- And also as an aside: I would strongly recommend against ever using aliases like this. Aliases are just for you to type on the command line, but processes (such as `make`) will likely not know about your aliases.